# Close all controls which has specific type

Tags: vb.net

I would like to create function which could take as parameter either usercontrol or windows form and then close all controls on it which are currently opened but only when type of them are either usercontrols or windows forms.

Below find my tries pseudo code:

```
'take as parameter either usercontrol or winform
Public Shared Sub DisposeUserControlControls(ucOrWinForm As T)

Dim type as Type = GetType(ucOrWinForm)


        While type.Controls.Count > 0

'if uc.Control is type of UserControl or WindowsForms then --> close

            While type.Controls(0).Controls.Count > 0
                type.Controls(0).Controls(0).Dispose()
            End While

            type.Controls(0).Dispose()
        End While
        type.Controls.Clear()
    End Sub
```

Comment: @Steve how this have to be done, can you post your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit of a code smell.  No compelling reason to make it generic, it is just as valid to do this when, say, it is a Panel you want to empty.  Do beware that you'll only ever run into a Form object when you set its TopLevel property to False.  Since you are going to skip controls of the wrong flavor you cannot use the While-loop anymore.  You instead have to iterate backwards.  Like this:

```
Public Shared Sub DisposeUserControlControls(parent As Control)
    For ix As Integer = parent.Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim ctl = parent.Controls(ix)
        If (TypeOf ctl Is UserControl) Or (TypeOf ctl Is Form) Then
            ctl.Dispose()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have no idea what "index" you want to clear.  Guessing, disposing a control automagically also removes it from the parent's Controls collection.  That is why you have to iterate backwards.  The code is good as-is, no extra work is required.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Type (and it is incorrect because the Type class has no Controls property), you specify the type as a Control in the signature of your method. Both Form and UserControl derive from Control

So you can try with this code:

```
Public Sub DisposeUserControlControls(Of T As Control)(ucOrWinForm As T)
    While ucOrWinForm.Controls.Count > 0
        ucOrWinForm.Controls(0).Dispose()
    End While
    ucOrWinForm.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: ye but we still missing code to close only those control which are also either UserControls or Windows forms

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean with _close_. You can call this method passing a Form or any kind of Control (UserControl or not).

Comment: yes thats ok, but then i dont want to close all controls on it but rather only those controls which are already opened of type either windows forms or user controls.